# Rails ActiveResource - Is it possible to bind only the model, and not the controller as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, activeresource, restful-architecture

I've built a Rails app about a year ago. After a couple of months, the possibility of making it multi-platform appeared, so I had to build a RESTful service in order to re-use functionalities.

One of the things that I want with this Rails 3 app is to change it as less as possible, so, I found ActiveResource in order to bind the model, but then I figured that I also needed to create a controller for it, and I just wanted to keep using the one that belongs to my app, because I believe it will be too time consuming to move my controller's logic to the service.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What's different other than what's being rendered to the client?

Comment: I don't know actually...will validations and everything else work as if the controller were on the same app? Because, I mean, now I will only have ActiveResource models and Views on my app, and ActiveRecord models and controllers on the REST service. If it works without any issues, there won't be any problems.

Comment: Oh, you mean you're creating two separate apps?

Comment: I've got two apps: one if the Rails 3 REST service and the other is a Rails 3 web application.

Comment: For example, in the ActiveResource docs there's no comments about having a controller on the service side in order to make it work. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html

Comment: Any ideas??? I cannot find a solution for this.